# Compile specific kernel module for my router's kernel version

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, buildroot

I've a router that runs Linux kernel version of 2.6.33, it came without tun/tap support.
The cpu is MIPSlittle endien. I setup a buildroot and successed 
compile "Hello world" program for the router.

I'm trying to compile tun.c from linux-kernel-2.6.33/drivers/net/tun.c as a standalone kernel object.
But I have not successed yet!
I use buildroot to get the header files for the kernel (by make menuconfig) and setup a Makefile for tun.c:

```
obj-m := tun.o
KDIR=/opt/buildroot/output/build/linux-kernel-2.6.33
PWD=$(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

I run the make file with

> make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/buildroot/output/bin/buildroot-compiler-

I got warnings and erros:

> Warning: Symbol version dump /opt/buildroot/output/build/linux-kernel-2.6.33/Module.symvers is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.
>
> include/linux/mmzone.h:18:30: fatel error: generated/bounds.h. No such or directory
>   .#include

Which one of my steps are wrong?

Comment: Show the exact error.

Comment: so you are compiling a module for an older kernel version then it was meant for? your title states that but i don't see that is your code so i am a little confused

Comment: @jgr208 I am trying to compile 2.6.33 kernel module within the linux kernel tree (tun.c)

Comment: the problem is the header file is not there it appears, the first is a warning and has no effect. look for the file in `/usr/include`

Comment: try `cd /usr/src/linux && make modules_prepare `

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting you're trying to build your module against a pure,
unconfigured kernel source tree.  you can't do that. Your kernel tree
must, at the *very* least, be configured and, more than that, it
should have `make modules_prepare` run at the top level.

Running `cd /usr/src/linux && make modules_prepare` should solve your problem.

Comment: You must also use a kernel configuration that corresponds to what is used on the board. Also, it is not /usr/src/linux but the extracted linux-2.6.33. I edited the answer accordingly.